# How to automatically execute a widget without any input

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to flutter and i would like make a widget that automatically execute every time at the start of dart file coming from other dart file.

This is the button that I would like to be automatically execute:

```
onPressed: isConnected ? () => _sendMessage('1') : null
```

Kindly make it a widget so i can understand easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  [initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/initState.html) method in your `stateful` widget, which is called when the page is inserted into Widget tree.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
if(isConnected)
_sendMessage('1')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you wants to execute `onPress` event every time whenever you redirect to that dart file from another file.

In this case you can add this function to `initState()` method at start of your file
refer : [here](https://medium.com/filledstacks/how-to-call-a-function-on-start-in-flutter-stateless-widgets-28d90ab3bf49)

or simply create a function and call it at start of file.

If you want something different can you please elaborate more.